# How to select a row in TableView (QML)?

Tags: qt, qml, qt6

In Qt 6, all QtQuick 1 components are removed. I want to rewrite an old application using Qt 6. The application uses the TableView control version 1.

How can I select a row in a new control TableView and get the values of all cells in the row?

Comment: Are you using Qml? You can add MouseArea on TableViews delegate and call Qt function from [OnEntered](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-mousearea.html#entered-signal) signal with (row ,column) pair as params

Comment: @Nikxp, How do I access all delegates in a row?

Comment: You can use Qt models https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-modelviewsdata-cppmodels.html. If you do - you can get access to model through Qt code.

Comment: QAbstractItemModel::sibling(...) function may be usefull https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html#sibling

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've had the same problem. Here's what worked for me.

I use *Qt 5.12* and `TableView` from *QtQuick 2.12*.

I had troubles with getting an index of clicked row. I've found that the [DelegateChooser](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qt-labs-qmlmodels-delegatechooser.html) and [DelegateChoice](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.12/qml-qt-labs-qmlmodels-delegatechoice.html) components allows you to access the row and column properties in `TableView`. After you got *row* and *column* form `DelegateChoice` you can use it to access data in model with `QAbstractItemModel` methods [index(...)](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html#index) and [data(...)](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html#data) like:

```
var idx = model.index(row, column)
var data = model.data(idx)
```

Here's full example:

```js
    import QtQuick 2.12             // TableView
    import Qt.labs.qmlmodels 1.0    // DelegateChooser
    
    // ...
    
    TableView {  
      id: usersTable
      model: tableModel
      
      anchors.fill: parent
      
      delegate: DelegateChooser
      {
        DelegateChoice
        {
          delegate: Rectangle {
            implicitWidth: 100
            implicitHeight: 50
            Text { text: display }
            
            MouseArea {
              anchors.fill: parent
              onClicked:
              {            
                // print value from clicked cell
                var idx = tableModel.index(row,column)
                console.log("Clicked cell: ", tableModel.data(idx))
                
                // print values from all cells in a row
                console.log("Clicked row: ")
                for (var i = 0; i < tableModel.columnCount(); i++)
                {
                  var idx2 = tableModel.index(row,i)
                  var data = tableModel.data(idx2)
                  console.log(data)
                }
              } // onClicked
            } // MouseArea
          } // Rectangle
        }// DelegateChoice
      } // DelegateChooser
    } // TableView
```

`DelegateChooser` allows you to create multiple delegates for the model. I'm not sure whether it's good practice or not to use chooser in case you have only one delegate (like in example above). But that workaround works perfectly fine.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use ItemDelegate for the delegates, using scoped `model.display` to access the model data (itemDelegate has an inherited *display* property). You must also explicitly handle the currently selected row, and with those to item, in a simple case this should work

```
    property int selectedRow: 1

    delegate: ItemDelegate {
        highlighted: row == view.selectedRow
        onClicked: view.selectedRow = row
        text: model.display
    }
```